# When sharing a folder in LAN, can I see what files are getting downloaded, and by whom?

Tags: windows, network-shares, monitoring

When sharing a folder in LAN, can I see what files are getting downloaded, and by whom?

What software can I use for this? I use Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

You can see who is currently connected to a network share and what files they have open.  I don't know of anything that logs that data if that's what you are looking for.

To view current connections:

1. Right-click on My Computer
2. Choose Manage
3. Expand Shared Folders
4. Expand the Open Files

Comment: interesting, but some logging would be useful.

Comment: Could always use the openfiles command (link below), which doesn't have logging but you could script it to run every x seconds or minutes, and dump the output to a file.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490961.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. Windows doesn't keep a log over accessed files. My suggestion is to setup a FTP server.

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a free FTP server and Client with user accounts and logging.

Comment: a good suggestion, but ftp is not allowed on the network

Comment: Is it to be used internally on a LAN or from WAN (Internet port 21 blocked)?

Comment: internally on LAN

Comment: Then I have no good suggestion other than convince them to accept FTP :D Sorry.

Comment: Another possibility is WebDAV, which Windows can access natively.